# Honest causal decision trees

Tags: rpart

Is there anyone who is familiar with honest causal decision trees? What is the purpose of the same and how can I implement it in my code in R? I am looking into the predictors (cognitive, non-cognitive, and family level predictors) of adolescent academic performance.